# Angular pattern validation

Tags: regex, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I need to validate a pattern on my input text field user only should enter 2018-2019 (4 digit number - 4 digit number) pattern I don't know how to write my Custom validation function.

Comment: Did you understand my question ............. sounds good I will try it

Answer (score 2):

For accuracy's sake I'd suggest `(?:19\d\d|2\d{3})-(?:19\d\d|2\d{3})`

This makes it so users can only enter dates within the 20th century and beyond. If you want to limit it to the 20th-21st you can use this: `(?:19\d\d|20\d\d)-(?:19\d\d|20\d\d)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iov7Du/1)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a validator for that. You can use the Validators.pattern function which takes your regex in parameter. https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern

Answer (score 0):

Angular 4 has added `Validators.min` and `Validators.max` (see [docs](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-4-min-max-validation)) to validate min and max number in a reactive form.`

```
userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     num1: ['', Validators.min(15)],
     num2: ['', Validators.max(50)]
});
```

e.g.

```
<input formControlName="num1">
<input formControlName="num2">
```

You can show validation error message as following:

```
<div *ngIf="num1.errors?.min">
      Minimum required number is 15.
</div> 
<div *ngIf="num2.errors?.max">
      Maximum number can be 50.
</div>
```